# Cannot read property 'select2' of null with image option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

hello i try to add image in my dropdown i use select2 lib to generate my list

select2 Version: 3.5.4 (i can't update)

UPDATE my code
hello thanks for your help ...  @SachaM78
i udpate my code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        fcfield_addrint.initAutoComplete("custom_field17_0", "field17");
        fcfield_addrint.initMap("custom_field17_0", "field17");

        // load image in select
        function format(state) {
        console.log(state);
        if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup custom_field17_0_custom_marker
        return (
          '<img class="fla" src="images/icons/' +
          state.id.toLowerCase() +
          '.png"/>' +
          state.text
        );
      }
      $("#custom_field17_0_custom_marker").select2({
        formatResult: format,
        formatSelection: format,
        escapeMarkup: function(m) {
          return m;
        }
      });

    });
```

And

```
<select id="custom_field17_0_custom_marker" name="custom[field17][0][custom_marker]" class="fc_gm_custom_marker" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/2hand.png">2hand.png</option>
    <option value="http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/360degrees.png">360degrees.png</option>
    <option value="http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/_readme-license.txt">_readme-license.txt</option>
    <option value="http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/abduction.png">abduction.png</option>
    <option value="http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/aboriginal.png">aboriginal.png</option>
    <option value="http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/accesdenied.png">accesdenied.png</option>
</select>
```

that return this

> index.php?option=com_flexicontent&task=item.edit&view=item&id=13:824
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select2' of null
>        at HTMLDocument. (index.php?option=com_flexicontent&task=item.edit&view=item&id=13:824)
>        at u (jquery.min.js?a84f5770d385cc79fd5efcfeaebe6f82:2)
>        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js?a84f5770d385cc79fd5efcfeaebe6f82:2)
>        at Function.ready (jquery.min.js?a84f5770d385cc79fd5efcfeaebe6f82:2)
>        at HTMLDocument._ (jquery.min.js?a84f5770d385cc79fd5efcfeaebe6f82:2)

Comment: Hi and Hello to Stack Overflow! I fixed the indentation of your code so it can be read more easily, hope that was OK. Regarding your question: did you include jQuery and Select2 via `<script src="..."></script>` before you called `.select2()`?

Comment: yes thanks for ident correction !
yes select2 is already loaded in other part of my form

Comment: You're welcome :-). What happens if you call `.select2()` without any optional parameters like "formatResult"?

Comment: if i remove js like
```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  '.$dom_ready_js.'

  // load image in select
  function format(state) {
  if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
  return "<img class=\'fla`\' src=\'images/icons/" + state.id.toLowerCase() + ".png\'/>" + state.text;
  }
 
 });
 ';
```
no error and i have the select with select2 lib .. but no image inside

Comment: Could you add this as an edit to your question? Code in comments are always hard to read.

Comment: hello i do it ! some idea ?

Comment: I copy-pasted your above code without two lines starting with `fcfield_addrint` into a new [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/vqROmo) and it works so there's some other problem in your code. The backslash in front of the images ("\images") is not correct though, but this wouldn't cause the error you receive. Could it be that you part of the HTML code is loaded asynchronously so that `#custom_field17_0_custom_marker` is just not available yet on DOM-ready? BTW: if you want a user to be notified, you need to spell the name correctly ;-)

Comment: sorry @SaschaM78 for your name .... i try same update without 2 first line but nothing change ... i am a pro about js how i can check about dom-ready ?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready()` = "DOM ready". "DOM ready" means the browser received all HTML contents and parsed all elements in the DOM tree so the page can be rendered and displayed. Please try to create a [mre] in jsfiddle.net or Codepen.io to check if your problem can be reproduced there?

Comment: Any updates regarding your problem?

Comment: no i am blocked ... because form is realy difficult to synthetise ... its a bigger form

Answer (score 1):

Just had a look at your code and I found several issues that may somehow lead to the error you encounter.

1. `select2()` needs to be called on a `<select>` element but right now you call it on  a `<div>` element. With advanced formatting you may apply it on any element but I currently think you wouldn't need it and go with a default SELECT element.
2. Your currently hidden `<select>` is missing the `</select>` element and is therefore invalid.
3. Your `format()` function uses incorrect escaping: you use double quotes around the string but then escape single quotes inside of the string. Also there is an accent in your string that does not seem to be right there.

Changed **HTML code**:

```
<select id="custom_field51_0_custom_marker" name="custom[field51][0][custom_marker]" 
        class="use_select2_lib fc_gm_custom_marker" tabindex="-1" title="Custom icon">
    <option value="">Sélectionner</option>
    <option value="C:\wamp64\www\flexidev/images/icons/1.png">1.png</option>
    <option value="C:\wamp64\www\flexidev/images/icons/2.png">2.png</option>
    <option value="C:\wamp64\www\flexidev/images/icons/3.png">3.png</option>
    <option value="C:\wamp64\www\flexidev/images/icons/4.png">4.png</option>
    <option value="C:\wamp64\www\flexidev/images/icons/5.png">5.png</option>    
</select> <!-- added missing end of SELECT
```

Changed **JS code**:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // load image in select
  function format(state) {
    console.log(state);
    if (!state.id) return state.text; // optgroup
    return (
      '<img class="fla" src="images/icons/' +
      state.id.toLowerCase() +
      '.png"/>' +
      state.text
    );
  }
  $("#custom_field51_0_custom_marker").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    escapeMarkup: function(m) {
      return m;
    }
  });
});
```

Current result:

[image: Demo image]

I created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexWayhill/pen/BgJpax) with a displayed `<select>` which shows missing image symbols in the dropdown as the referred images are not available online.

Comment: hello thanks for your help ...  @SachaM78
i udpate my code